# Volume of a silo using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the silo consisting of a cylinder with radius $3$ and height $10$ surmounted by a hemisphere.

Attempt at solution:

Equation of cylinder is $x²+y²=9$. The hemisphere has radius $3$ and center $(0,0,10)$

$-\sqrt{(9-r²)}+10 ≤ z ≤ \sqrt{(9-r²)}+10$

$0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π$

$0 ≤ r ≤ 3$

Are the limits of integration for $(r,θ,z)$ correct?

Comment: The lower limit for $z$ should represent the bottom of the silo, which lies on the $xy$-plane.